# In an MVC framework where should we put our NODE.js files?

Tags: php, node.js, directory-structure

I have a PHP framework. Recently I've put some burden on NODE.js shoulders. Now I don't know where to put node.js files. For now I have one file, but It'll get bloated in the near future. Where do you suggest to put these files?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT :**
I'm asking to see if putting nodejs files inside the php framework best practice. Or should we put all nodejs file in www folder without ever caring about our PHP framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put your node.js code in any web accessible folder (like www), as this is server code and it shouldn't be accessible from the web.
Your best bet is to just make another directory to host your node.js application which isn't in www or any other web accessible directory.

Comment: How did I not figure that out? Thank you. It makes sense to put it outside of the www dir.

Answer (score -1):

There must be some file named js, javascript, or script somewhere in your root folder. There you should put this file.

Comment: @phpGeek:- I don't know what framework you are using but generally it is good practice to put all your files in their respective folders of the framework so that they may be accessed properly by the framework engine.

Comment: Do you say that we can access NODE.js via PHP? Why would someone do that?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought node.js is some third party js library you are using. I don't know much about node.js so yoou can ignore my answer.

Comment: Why do people answer questions which they have absolutely no idea of? Node.js isn't standard browser javascript. It should be no where near your website's root folder.